# Can not get changes from child component in a nested angular Form

Tags: angular, typescript, nested-forms

I have a problem with getting changes from child component in nested angular form, this form is a dynamic form, which can be added new element.

I will post a part of my code

```
<div *ngFor="let evForm of evFormData.controls; let evseIndex = index">
      <div [formGroup]="evForm" class="column-separator">


<div
              *ngFor="let contact of evForm.get('contacts').controls; let contactIndex = index">
              <div [formGroupName]="contactIndex">
                <div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
                  <div class="parameterLabel step">connectorType</div>
                  <modification-dropdown
                  controlName="contactType"
                  [group]="connector.controls.connectorType"
                  [formControlValue]="contact"
              
                  ></modification-dropdown>

....
```

and this child component looks like this:

```
<label [formGroup]="group">
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <select class="parameterInputSelect" [formControlName]="controlName">
      <option *ngFor="let value of enumValues" [value]="value">
        {{value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</label>
```

and ts file looks like this:

```
export class ModificationDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() group: FormGroup;
  @Input() enumValues: string[];
  @Input() controlName: string;
  @Input() formControlValue: any;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.formData);
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      [this.controlName]: new FormControl(this.formData)
    });
  }

  get formData(): FormGroup {
    return this.formControlValue?.value[this.controlName] as FormGroup;
  }

}
```

But when I debug, I can not see any changes from my parent form, If I choose some value from dropdown

Maybe I did somthing wrong, any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a parent `form` element? There doesn't seem to be one in your template.

Comment: Do you mean you have a dynamic part of your form that you can add in and remove? If so you need to define a Form Array as a property of your form group?

Comment: Hi Ben, I have edited my post again, and I have added the paremtn form

Comment: Hi Darren, I think the Form Array will be used only, if the input value is array object isn`t it?